# People like to read their own names and not others? - UX Design - psychology

Tags: design, ux-designer, psychology, branding, logos

I read somewhere that people secretly hate to read the name(s) of other people/product over and over again. They only like to see their own names.

And that is why most people draw tattoos of their own names or their dynasty name and not others names and others dynasty name

And that's why Apple never writes "Apple" on the devices they make (not even on the startup screen or the rest of OS) and only use the logo instead. This is because they know that people don't want to read the name apple over and over again. If they did write "Apple" anywhere, users would start to secretly hate the name "Apple".

now my question is: Is it true? And if so, Is there any existing UX design principle says that use only the logo without the company name. Please share links to resources for proof. I want to read more about this topic.

Comment: personally, I think you've to separate brands from people names, two completely different things. People LOVE attaching themselves to brands as a form of identification. And while this is easily verifiable by hundreds of studies, you don't need any study on the subject, just go take a walk and see it by yourself. Not to mention that if that study is true, all social media would be doomed.

Comment: *And that's why Apple never writes "Apple" on the devices they make*. Sorry. I **really** need a reference for this. For starters, Apple is a physical brand, so it doesn't to have the name on the screen of an operative system which is NOT named *Apple*. Brand recognition and simplicity (and all the influence of Dieter Rams as we're at it) has a lot more to do with Apple not writing the company name on a screen than *"people hating other people name"*. Please add some proof, so other users can answer this

Comment: ----1) https://allisonrokeefe.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/applelogos.png
----2) https://www.logodesignlove.com/images/classic/apple-ii-logo-01.jpg

the logo was with name previously, they removed name from logo then

Comment: *Apple is a physical brand, so it doesn't to have the name on the screen* i think samsung and IBM are also physical products

Comment: I just read that stuff somewhere(i cant share link i forget to bookmark) and my question is that **Is it true? is something like this (or even near this) exist in UX or not?** and i'm also looking for proof i want proof from you :-)

Comment: @KitangaNday tried to answer really good, i appreciate

Comment: I know Apple used the name in its logo at som epoint, and I even explained why. You're LITERALLY asking if this is because people hate to see other people's name. Completely unrelated and even worse, undocumented, only hearsay. See how the answers are completely different and nobody is sure what are you asking.

Comment: On a google forum someone complained about chrome.
Chrome Team: "do x and **your** chrome will be fine"

Comment: @InzamamMalik It's also possible that Apple don't put their name on their products anymore because they feel that their iconic logo is strong enough. Positive reinforcement of one's self-identity ('ego stroking') is, of course, a powerful engagement tool but I'm not sure that having other names/identities present is harmful to engagement. As Devin says, I would need to see some evidence of the claims you make for Apple's reasoning before I could comment on that.

Comment: @ImranBughio I'm interested to read that thread can you please share link of that? infact i didn't get the point by 'do x and your chrome'

Comment: @InzamamMalik can't remember the link but the point was using the words like "**your chrome**" can be one of those tricks that can make someone feel more attached to a product they are complaining about ...

Comment: @AndrewMartin thank you very much for using this word ('ego stroking')

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: All these things can be summed up in one word: [personalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personalization).**

**(You want the user to feel like they own this, when a user feels like that, there's a emotional connection. That emotional connection will lead to a user having a harder time leaving your software. But yes, the "principle name" is "Personalization")**

**EDIT: Sorry for the large amount of text. It just keeps on connecting to other topics, and I can't control it. Just read paragraph one and you'll be good.**

I think it definitely is true, other examples of this would be in some first person shooter games, where to immerse you in the game, not much is said about the character you control. The character usually doesn't even speak much. It's meant to make the experience personal, and yes, I know, they probably didn't do that because we secretly hate to about others, but I'm certain you get the connection. Windows also never actually tells you that it's Windows (Windows 10 at least doesn't tell you it's Windows 10, you only see it's light blue logo of four squares).

A more common occurrence of what you mentioned (the hating of seeing other people's names mentioned), is when usually seen between women. Ever notice how pissed a woman can get when another woman does something better than her, whether it's dressing better, getting more attention, even dating a guy the former has interest in (You so much as mention the latter woman's name and you've pretty much signed your death sentence). Your finding, for me at least, sounds a lot like it's connected to this occurrence. And I think some designers have caught onto this and tried to make it more personal. Maybe it's because of fear that even if the user might not be female they might still "secretly" have these types of emotions.

Human beings have always been bent on finding things that match up with what they like, or at least that something is similar to you. And whether you are a guy named "joy" you will still enjoy meeting someone (male/female) who has the same name. There's also group think, how we like to go after things that match up with what we think things should be like (our perception of things). This could be going to websites that have the same political views as we do, having friends who have the same beliefs or value the same things as we do, etc. This image best describes this:

[image: jackpot]

What i'm trying to say is that, trying to connect with someone on a personal level usually means you have to make things about them rather than you. Even using the word "you" (or was it "my") in a signup form could lead to more signups. When it comes to UX it's all about the user and putting them center stage. If you fail to do this, or refuse to acknowledge this, your users will definitely ignore your tool/software and find an alternative that succeeds in putting them center stage.

---

**References:**

[The Complete Guide to Understanding Consumer Psychology](https://www.quicksprout.com/the-complete-guide-to-understand-customer-psychology/)(Please read this, even though it's aimed more at marketers than at UX devs):

- If you read [Chapter One](https://www.quicksprout.com/the-complete-guide-to-understand-customer-psychology-chapter-1/), you'll get to a section whose title is ""You"": [image: The Complete Guide to Understanding Consumer Psychology chapter 2 - "You" section]
- In [chapter five](https://www.quicksprout.com/the-complete-guide-to-understand-customer-psychology-chapter-5/) you are reminded to use "You" and shown how to do this more effectively (I think it does. I just schemed over it): [image: The Complete Guide to Understanding Consumer Psychology chapter 5 - Use The Word "You" section]

[Silent Protagonist can lead to immersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_protagonist#Critical_reaction)

Personalization (a.k.a. customization):

- [The Psychology of Personalization: Why We Crave Customized Experiences](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/psychology-personalization)
- [Study by University of Texas](https://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/handle/2152/18054)

Comment: This is all true, but I don't think it answers the question, maybe OP can shed a light on whether it does. How I read it, he explains something with an example of personal names, to get to the point of why a brand should or shouldn't constantly use it's name. This does not seem to be about personal names.

Comment: @MJB I changed it, but couldn't bring myself to delete the rest of it.

Comment: @KitangaNday no need to delete its good

Comment: I voted you up :-)

Comment: i edit in my question little to make clear what my question is, i declare that the question was not clear

Comment: @InzamamMalik thanks for the vote. I see that you need some evidence to some of my claims. You will love the reference I give you

Comment: @KitangaNday tried to answer really good, i appreciate you effort, i want to read more about this topic but i still dont have any particular 'principle name' which my question is related to e.g: i can search UX about color with simple keyword 'color sense'.

Comment: @InzamamMalik I added that. Please tell me if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that people tend to have certain biased towards brands in general because of what they want to be associated with.

For instance; a man that isn't very confident about his own masculinity won't want to be associated with a brand that has a pink color because the color does not boost his masculinity (or atleast it would seem so in most societies). Brand- or companynames can also be effected by this principle.

Whether or not this is a concern to your brand depends on your target audience. If your main business is products that have a big effect on people's lifestyles, it is something to think about. If you're more focussed on products for habitual buying behaviour, it's mostly less of a concern. (for instance, groceries)

[Source - Brands as a Mean of Consumer Self-expression and Desired Personal Lifestyle](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877042813050593)

Comment: Actually, when it comes to the buying of items, signup forms, it's advised to make it personal. Make it all about the user.

Comment: Well yes, but that's not the question is it? I thought this question was about if there are theories in psychology which explains why people are drawn to certain names, and why some brands use logo's rather than names. The last line is "is there something thing similar exist in ux design like not not write name just place logo etc?" So I'm guessing this question is not about opening an e-mail with "Hi Kitanga".

Comment: Ey, lol, I see what you did there. Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question a little bit. Going to edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @KitangaNday Haha yeah the question was kind of unclear, so when you started about personal names I started doubting me own answer aswell

Comment: It was just meant to explain why the "users hate other's names" thing is true, by connecting to another "issue" (?) that I know of. BTW, that example for men is sport on, I had (or I might still have...) it. Now that I've read your answer, I'm more confused as to what we are supposed to be answering. Anywhere OP will choose, yes?

Comment: Don't forget to add references, it's required now.

Comment: @KitangaNday Oh is that required these days? I'll see if I can find the references from my study books ;)

Comment: lol, I know, took a bit for me to remember where on Earth to get references. If the references are even right that is. But yea, that addition could get your answer accepted. You never know.

Answer (score 2):

There's something called the cocktail party effect.

Its generally about how we 'tune out' all the other conversations in a room.

However, our brain actually monitors what's going on in the background and if it hears our name in one of the other conversations it will switch focus to that conversation.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_party_effect

So our name is something which will 'grab our attention'.

And every other name we ignore.

Comment: appreciate your effort